# What is the easiest way to launch SSD machine on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is the easiest way to launch SSD machine on AWS? Under my AWS account all the linux images that I have an option to pick states that the root device type as EBS and when I am trying to launch an instance of **i2.2xlarge** it says by default

```
Root /dev/sda1
instance store 0: /dev/sdb
instance store 1: /dev/sdc
```

Now when I do some performance measurements such as write some data to file and calling fsync the **i2.2xlarge** machine which claims to have inbuilt SSD seems to be 100X slower than **m3.xlarge** which doesnt come with instance store and has only EBS as its root. so I suspect highly that there is something wrong with these machines. any ideas? I have tried it with Ubuntu AMI and Amazon Linux AMI's (the latest one available) and I got the same result.

Comment: The m3.xlarge instance type does have instance storage (1 x 32 GB SSD). Do you mean you launched an m3.xlarge with just an EBS root?

Comment: I just want to know how do I make sure my instance access only local SSD but not go through EBS?

Comment: An instance's boot volume can be backed by either EBS or an instance-store volume. Which is used is determined by the AMI. Using instance-store boot volume is not recommended as they are ephemeral. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html for more info.

Comment: In out i2.2xlarge the root device (/dev/sda1) can be either EBS (which can be SSD) or instance-store (which you don't know the type as AWS want to deprecate them), this depend of the type of AMI you select.  The /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc are ephemeral local sotrage which in case of i2 are SSD.